# Search seiries in a array (PHP)

Tags: php, csv, echo

I have php output like this:

```
data00,data01,data02,data03, , , and so on
data10,data11,data12,data13, , , and so on
data20,data21,data22,data23, , , and so on
(and so on in rows)
```

And this php code that generate this data.

```
<?php
$searchthis = $_GET["sea1"];
$matches = array();

$handle = @fopen("sources.csv", "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        if(strpos($buffer, $searchthis) !== FALSE)
            $matches[] = $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

//show results:
print_r($matches);
```

Now I want to show a specific line on a specific column somewhere in the page
and if I use:

```
<?php echo $matches[0]; ?>
```

it will show me the whole line, and not the specific data that i want.
i can make something like this:

```
$output = echo $matches[0]
```

but then? how I should use the $output ?? for example if i need the second word instead of or the whole line.

now, after the the answer i update my files to looks like this: pls see if i am somewhere wrong, becouse is now not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>my page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <title>My Page</title>
      <form name="myform" action="systemmonitor.php" method="GET">
        <div align="center">My page<br>
          <br>
          <input name="sea1" placeholder="customtext" size="25" type="text"> <br>
          <br>
          <input name="sea2" placeholder="customtext" size="25" type="text"> <br>
          <br>
          <input name="sea" value="submit" type="submit"><br>
          <br>
<?php
$searchthis = $_GET["sea1"];
$matches = array();

$handle = @fopen("systemlines.csv", "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (($buffer = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $check = preg_grep("/$searchthis/",$buffer);
        if(!empty($check)){
            $matches[] = $buffer;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

//show results:
print_r($matches);?>
  </body>
</html>
<?php echo $matches[0][4]; ?>
```

Comment: you could use `explode(",",$matches[0])`

Comment: This would be a lot simpler using a relational database

Comment: Could you supply some of the output of print_r($matches) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `fgetcsv` instead of `fgets`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

**UPD**

```
<?php
$searchthis = $_GET["sea1"];
$matches = array();

$handle = @fopen("sources.csv", "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (($buffer = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $check = preg_grep("/$searchthis/",$buffer);
        if(!empty($check)){
            $matches[] = $buffer;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

//show results:
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: and then? what i have to do?

Comment: In `$matches` you would have array of array.
`$matches[0]` - array of all elements in 1st row (array('data00','data01',...)), `$matches[0][0]` -> `data00`

Comment: it works but now $matches show the full csv and not the lines that contains the specific keyword as it used to be with ''fgets''. see here: $searchthis = $_GET["formdata"];

Comment: Fixed. Change `strpos` to `preg_grep`. `preg_grep` work with array.
Sorry, don't look for `strpos` in first try.

Comment: still show all the stuff, and not the lines that i want, i mean before i was search for a keyword and server output the lines with this keyword, and if no keyword=no lines, now it shows my all the lines of the csv, the $matches[0][0] its works but shows from all the stuff.

Comment: still is not working, the output is only ''Array ( )'' see my update question, maybe am do something wrong.